# Adding a company Logo to ShinyDashboard header

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

So just curious, is there any way to add a company logo to the header of a ShinyDashboard? As I am looking at the [documentation](http://rstudio.github.io/shinydashboard/appearance.html#css), it describes changing the "logo" in the CSS, this is just configuring what goes in the upper left hand corner though as far as I can tell and I would like to keep my title there.

I am not using the drop down menus and so I would like to add my company logo on the top right where the red box is.

[image]

Does anyone have any idea how this can be done with Shinydashboard? Thanks.

**Update 2020-10-27**

For users that are comfortable with HTML or want more flexibility around their user interface and have access to a front end developer, I recently discovered you can use HTML to build the entire user interface. There is a Shiny article about it [here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/html-ui.html). This would allow the entire branding and layout to be done in a way that could comply with your company standards if desired. Hope this helps.

Comment: This might help.  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21996887/embedding-image-in-shiny-app

Comment: For future readers: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70687027/9841389) is another approach for centered images using `htmltools::tagQuery`.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

I've been working with a bit of a hack for this, (and I know you didn't ask for it, but here's a clickable logo while we're at it):

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

dbHeader <- dashboardHeader()
dbHeader$children[[2]]$children <-  tags$a(href='http://mycompanyishere.com',
                                           tags$img(src='logo.png',height='60',width='200'))

dashboardPage(
       dbHeader,
       dashboardSidebar(),
       dashboardBody()
)
```

So this nests a shiny.tag inside the header. The second slot in this particular shiny object is the logo slot (You'll need a 'logo.png' in your /www/ folder in the app directory)

EDIT:

I just checked, and as of right now, this hack should no longer be necessary, you can insert the html directly from the dashboardHeader function via the `title=` parameter, (Before, that parameter was enforcing text only),

I think the answer might still be useful as a method to modify existing shiny functions where things *ARE* hardcoded in though.

**Here's the method now:**

```
dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title = tags$a(href='http://mycompanyishere.com',
                                    tags$img(src='logo.png')))
```

or, adding a little more magic to the logo (I also use my logo as a loading bar):

```
# Takes a location 'href', an image location 'src', a loading gif 'loadingsrc'
# height, width and alt text, and produces a loading logo that activates while
# Shiny is busy
loadingLogo <- function(href, src, loadingsrc, height = NULL, width = NULL, alt = NULL) {
  tagList(
    tags$head(
      tags$script(
        "setInterval(function(){
                     if ($('html').attr('class')=='shiny-busy') {
                     $('div.busy').show();
                     $('div.notbusy').hide();
                     } else {
                     $('div.busy').hide();
                     $('div.notbusy').show();
           }
         },100)")
  ),
  tags$a(href=href,
         div(class = "busy",  
             img(src=loadingsrc,height = height, width = width, alt = alt)),
         div(class = 'notbusy',
             img(src = src, height = height, width = width, alt = alt))
   )
  )
}

dashboardBody(
  dashboardHeader(title = loadingLogo('http://mycompanyishere.com',
                                      'logo.png',
                                      'loader.gif'),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody()
)
```

Comment: how can I change the alignment of the logo?

Comment: That's all going to be css styling. There are two ways to do that, one is to wrap the children in tags$style(..). The other (And probably preferred method), would be to create a custom.css file and put it in your /www/ folder. Then call it with `tags$head(tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css", href = "custom.css")` . Inside the stylesheet just add `.logo {ALIGNMENTPARAMS: VALUE;}` where you can find the names of the parameters and values via google.

Comment: @Shape with shiny 0.13.2 and shinydashboard 0.5.1 the solution doesn't seem to work: I get `the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: @Enzo those are the versions I have, and it still works for me, make sure the link is right and the logo.png is in your www folder

Comment: 404 sounds like something different though, that sounds like there's an issue with your hosting

Comment: I discovered the issue:  you need to have separate ui.R and server.R files, otherwise if you are using all in a single app.R file with shinyApp(ui, server), it does not "find" the logo.png file in the www folder (but it does find my favicon.ico - boh?).

Answer (score 45):

Here's my hack (put your logo, as has been mentioned before, into a `www` subdirectory of your app directory).
Because `dashboardHeader()` expects a tag element of type `li` and class `dropdown`, we can pass such elements instead of `dropdownMenu`s:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

dbHeader <- dashboardHeader(title = "My Dashboard",
                            tags$li(a(href = 'http://shinyapps.company.com',
                                      icon("power-off"),
                                      title = "Back to Apps Home"),
                                    class = "dropdown"),
                            tags$li(a(href = 'http://www.company.com',
                                      img(src = 'company_logo.png',
                                          title = "Company Home", height = "30px"),
                                      style = "padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:10px;"),
                                    class = "dropdown"))

server <- function(input, output) {}

shinyApp(
    ui = dashboardPage(
        dbHeader,
        dashboardSidebar(),
        dashboardBody()
    ),
    server = server
)
```

Comment: If someone doesn't need it to be clickable - I suggest changing `a()` for `div()` and adding `margin-right:10px;` to the style parameter.

Comment: Due to recent rule change in browser processing, minor change is required to the img.  Change `img(src=...)` to `tags$img(src=...)`.

Comment: The size of the image has anything to do with it?