# How to add a company Logo to ShinyDashboard header (Not mainPanel or mainHeader)

Tags: css, shinydashboard

I tried to refer to below answers but the logo is locate inside the main panel but not the header panel... Any solution?

- [Adding a company Logo to ShinyDashboard header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31440564/adding-a-company-logo-to-shinydashboard-header)
- [Embedding Image in Shiny App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21996887/embedding-image-in-shiny-app)
- [Add company logo to every page using Rstudio and knitr [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32138358/add-company-logo-to-every-page-using-rstudio-and-knitr)

[image: HeaderLogo]

I saw that [DISTRIBUTIONS OF RANDOM VARIABLES](http://www.showmeshiny.com/distributions-of-random-variables/) has a logo inside main panel's header but unable to work in shinyDashboard header. Below is the coding for the company logo header:

```
headerPanel(
        HTML('Distributions of Random Variables v4
            <a href="http://snap.uaf.edu" target="_blank"><img align="right" alt="SNAP Logo" src="./img/SNAP_acronym_100px.png" /></a>'
        ), "Distributions of Random Variables"
    ),
```

Below is my coding for adding company logo and the [source codes](https://github.com/scibrokes/analyse-the-finance-and-stocks-price-of-bookmakers) is here. Any idea?

```
dbHeader <- dashboardHeader(title = 'Reporting Dashboard',
            dropdownMenuOutput('messageMenu'),
            dropdownMenu(type = 'notifications',
                         notificationItem(text = '5 new users today', icon('users')),
                         notificationItem(text = '12 items delivered', 
                                          icon('truck'), status = 'success'),
                         notificationItem(text = 'Server load at 86%', 
                                          icon = icon('exclamation-triangle'), 
                                          status = 'warning')),
            dropdownMenu(type = 'tasks',
                         badgeStatus = 'success',
                         taskItem(value = 90, color = 'green', 'Documentation'),
                         taskItem(value = 17, color = 'aqua', 'Project X'),
                         taskItem(value = 75, color = 'yellow', 'Server deployment'),
                         taskItem(value = 80, color = 'red', 'Overall project')))
dbHeader$children$children <- HTML("<a href='http://www.scibrokes.com' target='_blank'>
                        <img align='right' alt='Logo' src='./oda-army.jpg'/></a>")
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

the solution is to **conceal** your image, such that `shiny` renders it like it would have rendered a normal `dropdownMenu` item.

As you might have seen from your console, `dashboardHeader` throws errors

```
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : Expected tag to be of type li
```

if you try to insert **any** custom HTML. And if you choose a `li` tag, it even elaborates

```
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : Expected tag to have class 'dropdown'
```

So here is your deal, add your image in a `li` wrapper with class `dropdown` and you are good to go.

Sample code:

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(shiny)

runApp(
  shinyApp(
    ui = shinyUI(
      dashboardPage(
          dashboardHeader(title = 'Reporting Dashboard',
            tags$li(class = "dropdown",
                    tags$a(href="http://snap.uaf.edu", target="_blank", 
                           tags$img(height = "20px", alt="SNAP Logo", src="https://www.snap.uaf.edu/sites/default/files/pictures/snap_symbol_color.png")
                    )
            ),
            dropdownMenuOutput('messageMenu'),
            dropdownMenu(type = 'notifications',
                         notificationItem(text = '5 new users today', icon('users')),
                         notificationItem(text = '12 items delivered', 
                                          icon('truck'), status = 'success'),
                         notificationItem(text = 'Server load at 86%', 
                                          icon = icon('exclamation-triangle'), 
                                          status = 'warning')),
            dropdownMenu(type = 'tasks',
                         badgeStatus = 'success',
                         taskItem(value = 90, color = 'green', 'Documentation'),
                         taskItem(value = 17, color = 'aqua', 'Project X'),
                         taskItem(value = 75, color = 'yellow', 'Server deployment'),
                         taskItem(value = 80, color = 'red', 'Overall project'))
          ),

          dashboardSidebar(),
          dashboardBody()
      )
    ), 

    server = function(input, output){}

  ), launch.browser = TRUE
)
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

```
dashboardBody( 
    tags$img(align="right",src="http://www.pagesolutions.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/Finalised-logo.png",height="50px"),
    tags$strong("PAGE SOLUTIONS",style="color:#0a90d3"),tags$p("CLASSIFICATION MODELING",style="color:black"),
    tags$p("Customer Classification"),
    ...
)
```