# R - Customize text in shinydashboard header

Tags: r, text, shiny, shinydashboard

To add text to my dashboard header I adopted the solution of the second answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45176030/add-text-on-right-of-shinydashboard-header) (with styles.css file). I have to insert dynamic text while the script only allows static text. My text is:

```
format(Sys.Date(), format="%A  %d %b %Y")
```

how to solve?

Comment: When in the linked solution by Tiffany do you want your custom text inserted? Part of `tags$script`? `tags$head`? or `styles.css`?

Answer (score 1):

Below are the two different solutions if you want to display dynamic dates on header in Shiny.

This code will be helpful if you need to use `shinydashboard` package

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

header <- dashboardHeader(
  title = "dynamicDates",
  tags$li(class = "dropdown", tags$a(HTML(paste(uiOutput("Refresh1"))))))
body <- dashboardBody()
sidebar <- dashboardSidebar()

ui <- dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$Refresh1 <- renderText({
    toString(format(Sys.Date(), format = "%A  %d %b %Y"))
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

In this code i'm not using `shinydashboard` package. With plain `shiny` functions in combination of few `HTML tags` we can customize as per need.

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage( 
  titlePanel("", windowTitle = "Dynamic Dates"),
  titlePanel(title = tags$div(img(src = "https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/shiny.png", width = 125, height = 115, align = "left"))),
  titlePanel(title = tags$div(class = "header" , tags$p("Dynamic", tags$b(" Dates"),style = "text-align: center; color:navy;"), style = "text-align: center; color:navy;")),
  titlePanel(title = tags$div(uiOutput("dynamicDate"), align = 'right')))

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$dynamicDate <- renderUI(toString(format(Sys.Date(), format = "%A  %d %b %Y")))
  }
shinyApp(ui, server)
```