# Adding reactive text to the section above the main panel of shiny dashboard

Tags: r, shiny, dashboard, reactive, dashboardheader

I'm hoping to add reactive data coming in from an API into the section above the main panel, like the attached photo. It would be to the right of the dashboard header and centred.
[Click to see where in shiny output I would like the text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VuH54.png)

I am fairly new to working with shiny but have read some similar questions here [Add text on right of shinydashboard header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45176030/add-text-on-right-of-shinydashboard-header)

Any suggestions or resources to read would be super helpful.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO, did you try the solutions listed in the other post you mentioned? What would be different in your question?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.