# Dynamic title for shinydashboard(Plus)

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

When I define the `ui` for my `shinydashBoardPlus` app, I can define a title:

```
ui <- shinydashboardPlus::dashboardPage(
    header=shinydashboardPlus::dashboardHeader(title="My App", 
    ...
```

However, I would like to use the space right to the Hamburger menu for dynamically set text (e.g. the current work modus). Like this:

[image: Example Title]

I would like this because I have several tabs that work on the same "group", so I can not include this information in the tab itself.

Is that possible and how?

Comment: I came across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45176030/add-text-on-right-of-shinydashboard-header) - do any of these answers help (just with `shinydashboard`)?

Comment: The second answer works perfectly! Thanks for pointing me there. I also found out that `font-family: "Source Sans Pro"` looks good.