# Navigation bar Toggle button on left of title in R shinydashboard

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I have a R shiny app using shinydashboard. I want logo in center and side bar toggle button (with three horizontal bars) on left side of the screen.

I am using 95% of titlewidth with logo in center using below code. But, this pushes navigation bar with toggle button on right 5% screen. **How can I switch navigation bar to be on left (as shown in picuture) and title bar with logo in center? **

[image]

```
dashboardHeader(title = tags$a(tags$img(src='Logo.png', height=80)), 
 titleWidth = "95%")
```

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Thanks,
Krina

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's probably a better way, but here's a hacky option:

1. [Conceal the logo as a `dropdownMenu`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36062742/8099834)
2. Move logo to the center of the header [using css](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23384995/8099834)
3. (Optional) Remove the css `hover` effect from the logo

Other `dropdownMenus` remain right-aligned.

[image]

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

css <- HTML(
    "/* move logo to center */
    #logo {
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        top: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }
    /* remove hover effect */
    #logo > a:hover {
        background-color: transparent !important;
        color: transparent !important;
    }"
)

ui <- dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title = "Project Title",
                    tags$li(class = "dropdown",
                            id = "logo",
                            tags$a(tags$img(height = "20px",
                                            src="https://www.r-project.org/logo/Rlogo.png")
                            ),
                            tags$style(css)
                    ),
                    dropdownMenu(type = "messages", 
                                 badgeStatus = "primary",
                                 taskItem(value = 20, 
                                          "Example"
                                 ))
    ),
    dashboardSidebar(),
    dashboardBody()
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```