# Image won't appear from www folder in Shiny App

Tags: shiny

I'm following the code from this previous question: *[R Shiny add picture to box in fluid row with text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44279773/r-shiny-add-picture-to-box-in-fluid-row-with-text/44280142?noredirect=1#comment75567254_44280142)*

Here is my code:

```
box(title = "Instructions",
            status = "primary",
            solidHeader = F,
            collapsible = F,
            width = 12,
            fluidRow(column(width=10,textOutput("instructions")),
                     column(width=2, align="center",
                            img(src="no1.jpeg", width=100))))

server <- function(input, output) {

output$instructions <-renderText(print("test"))}

##Create and Run Shiny App Object---------------
shinyApp(ui, server)

runApp("~/shinyapp")
```

I think the location of my `www` folder is wrong. I put it in the same folder as my .Rpoj. I'm using a Mac

> /Users/myname/Desktop/ProjFolder/www:

I'm really not sure where else to put it, or how to get to the place where I need to put the `www` folder.

Comment: Check your current wd `getwd()`

Comment: It says my current wd is /Users/myname/Desktop/ProjFolder/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `www` folder should be in the same directory as the `app.R` file if your app is invoked with `runApp("path/to/appfolder")`. Your working directory only matters if you run `shinyApp(ui, server)` directly in the console. That is because `runApp` changes your working directory temporarily to the appfolder you point to.

If you want to use an absolute path to an image you can use [`addResourcePath`](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.0.2/addResourcePath.html) like so

```
addResourcePath(prefix = 'pics', directoryPath = '~/pictures')
ui <- fluidPage(
   tags$img(src = "pics/my_picture.jpg")  ## use the prefix defined in
                                          ## addResourcePath
)
server <- function(...) { }
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

`addResourcePath` can also be used to load JavaScript and CSS resources into your app.

### More on runApp()

Since this came up in the comments, I want to clarify some things about the behavior of `shiny::runApp()`. The first argument of this function can either be a path to an app or an app object. Examples

```r
dummy_app <- shinyApp(getwd(), function(...) {})
runApp("path/to/appfolder")  # path
runApp("path/to/app.R")      # path
runApp(dummy_app)            # app object
```

If a path is used, `runApp()` will change the working directory to the app directory (`path/to/appfolder` or `path/to`) until the app is finished. If an app object is passed, the current working directory is used as-is.

If an app object is printed as in

```r
class(dummy_app)
#> [1] "shiny.appobj"
dummy_app
```

this will invoke `shiny:::print.shiny.appobj` which references to `runApp(<appobj>)` so again, the working directory is preserved.

Comment: "`runApp` changes your working directory temporarily to the appfolder you point to" - is that true? I don't see that anywhere in https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/blob/master/R/runapp.R.

Comment: Changing the working directory is hidden more deeply in the implementation. See [R/shinyApp.R#L234](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/blob/e29d92c5ff00063778d0fee26eecc48d75eb3aee/R/shinyapp.R#L234). Basically, it makes a difference wether `runApp()` is used as `runApp(appobj)` or `runApp(path)` because `shiny::as.shiny.appobj()` is a S3 generic.

Comment: Exactly - a `shinyApp` generated by `shinyApp(ui, server)` (which the OP is using) does not even have the concept of an `appDir`, I think. It's `onStart` is `NULL` by default: https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/blob/e29d92c5ff00063778d0fee26eecc48d75eb3aee/R/shinyapp.R#L74

Comment: This is true. However, OP explicitly has `runApp("~/shinyapp")` in his question so I felt i needed to clarify this (often unexpected) behavior when I wrote my answer. If you use `runApp()` and point to an `app.R` file that has `shinyApp()` in the last line, the working directory is still changed to the parent directory of `app.R`.

Comment: This can be easily tested with a simple dummy app: `shiny::shinyApp("", function(...) print(getwd()))`.

Comment: Oh, very true. The OP seems to use a somewhat redundant call of shinyApp, followed by the (only?) relevant call to runApp

Comment: thank you @GregordeCillia! your detailed of using `addResourcePath()` helped solve my issue. I am trying to change to using multiple files for Shiny apps (ui.R, server.R, global.R...) and couldn't figure out why i couldn't add a simple .png image. Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Check out the suggestion [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/trouble-including-image-jpeg-png-svg-etc-in-shiny-app-embedded-in-r-package/56156). Solved the issue for me.
Move the "www" folder to "inst" and create a new R script containing the following in the folder .R.

```
.onLoad <- function(libname, pkgname) {
  shiny::addResourcePath(
    prefix = "www",
    directoryPath = system.file(
      "www",
      package = "name of your package"
    )
  )
}

.onUnload <- function(lib name, pkgname) {
   shiny::removeResourcePath("www")
}
```

When referring to images in the UI, it should look like this:

```
img(src = "www/image.jpg")  # prefix + filename
```