# Problem trying to publish a plot into shinyapps.io

Tags: r, plot, shiny, shinyapps

I am having some problems publishing my shinny app online which consists of a fairly simple plot. The entire r code I have tried is the following:

```
library(ggtext)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(readxl)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(patchwork)
library(hrbrthemes) 
library(ggbump) 
library(httpgd)
library(writexl)
library(here)
#library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(scales)

#getwd()

############################################################################
### Importing Datasets for Budget Constraing Analysis. #####################

Panel <- read.csv2("Consolidated BC LATAM.csv", header = TRUE)
##############################################################################


Data <- Panel %>%
  select(1:23)

glimpse(Data)

Data <- Data %>%
  mutate(`domestic debt` = as.numeric(domestic.debt ),
         `change in foreign debt` = as.numeric(change.in.foreign.debt),
         `change in total debt` = as.numeric(change.in.total.debt),
         `change in real money balance` = as.numeric(change.in.real.money.balance),
         `Inflation Tax` = as.numeric(Inflation.Tax),
         seigniorage = as.numeric(seigniorage),
         `primary deficit` = as.numeric(primary.deficit)) 


Data <- Data %>%
  mutate(Criterion_Dummy = ifelse(`change in total debt` <= 0 & seigniorage > 0 & `primary deficit` <= 0, 1, 0)) 

# Define UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Criterion and Inflation Rate Visualization"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("country", "Select Country:",
                  choices = unique(outcome$Country),
                  selected = unique(outcome$Country)[1]),
      sliderInput("x_range", "X-Axis Range:",
                  min = 1960, max = 2020, value = c(1960, 2020))
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("plot")
    )
  )
)

# Define server logic
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  filtered_data <- reactive({
    filter(outcome, Country == input$country & 
             year >= input$x_range[1] & year <= input$x_range[2])
  })
  
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(filtered_data(), aes(x = year, 
                                y = as.numeric(`Inflation Rate`),
                                color = factor(Criterion_Dummy),
                                group = 1)) +
      geom_point(alpha = 0.5) +
      geom_line() +
      geom_point(data = filtered_data() %>% filter(!is.na(`Stabilization Plan`)), 
                 aes(label = `Stabilization Plan`), 
                 alpha = 1, size = 4) +
      geom_text(data = filtered_data() %>% filter(!is.na(`Stabilization Plan`)), 
                aes(label = `Stabilization Plan`, 
                    x = year, 
                    y = as.numeric(`Inflation Rate`)), 
                hjust = -0.1, vjust = -0.5, size = 4) +
      labs(x = "Year", y = "Inflation Rate") +
      facet_wrap(~ Country) + 
      theme_ipsum() +
      scale_color_manual(name = "Criterion Dummy",  # Change legend title
                         labels = c("0" = "Criterion not met", "1" = "Fiscal Surplus + Positive Seigniorage + Debt Reduction"),  # Change legend labels
                         values = c("0" = "#FF5733", "1" = "#3498DB")) +
      theme(legend.position = "bottom")
  })
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I am aware of all the other questions similar to this one but non have helped. At first I thought it was a problem with the data upload but I after fixing that and turning the excel file into a csv the problem persists. Naturally the app works perfectly fine locally so I have no idea what could be causing this inconvenience.

I have been trying to publish a simple plot into shiny.io but I am not being able to.

Comment: You probably need top put `Consolidated BC LATAM.csv` in your app's `www` folder.  (If it doesn't have one yet, create it.)  Also, check to ensure that `Consolidated BC LATAM.csv` is a valid file name on shinyapps.io.

Comment: Sorry, it's my first time with shiny, could you refer me to a source on how to do that?

Comment: Create a `www` as a sub folder of your app's home folder.  Put your csv file in it.  See, for example, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51561179/image-wont-appear-from-www-folder-in-shiny-app).

Comment: `www` folder is for frontend  resources, e.g js, CSS & image files.  @Tlarre, unfortunately *" /../ not being able to"* is not too informative. How exactly are you publishing your app,  directly through `rsconnect` ? Or through publish button in RStduio IDE? Does it return an error while publishing? If yes, what's the error? Or is there an error when you access the app page? In that case, check logs though shinyapps.io dashboard for warnings / errors. Also, what is the file name of your app and how are you executing it locally?

Comment: I see the `library(shiny)` is commented out. The app may be running locally if you have shiny library attached locally. Also what error do you get when trying to load the app?

Comment: You may want to clean up the libraries you're loading, you only need to load them once.

Comment: I have deleted all of the libraries that I was not using, but I still have trouble publishing. I am trying to publish from the publish button in rstudio, after successfully creating an account for myself. I also tried simplifying the data input by inserting the csv as text in order to avoid the link problem, but it hasn't helped. The only error I find is An error has occurred
```
The application failed to start.

exit status 1 ``` The app is called app since I tried the template from rstudio to avoid further inconveniences and locally I execute it from the button.