# put a dropdown button on shinydashboard header for theme selection

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I want to put a dropdown menu on shinydashboard header for dashboard theme change. My shiny app is like below. I could not make the app work.  What I got is error message;

```
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : Expected tag to be of type li
```

It seems like the dashboard area does not accept those typical shiny widgets? The header area is the best place to put this functionality.  Does anyone know how I can make that work? Thanks a lot.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(dashboardthemes)


header <- dashboardHeader(
    title = "Dashboard Demo",
    dropdownButton(

        tags$h3("List of Themes:"),

        radioButtons(inputId = 'theme',
                     label = 'Dashboard Theme',
                     choices = c('blue_gradient', 'boe_website', 'grey_light','grey_dark',
                                 'onenote', 'poor_mans_flatly', 'purple_gradient'),
                     selected = 'grey_dark',
                     inline=FALSE),

        circle = TRUE, status = "primary",
        icon = icon("window-maximize"), width = "300px",

        tooltip = tooltipOptions(title = "Click to change dashboard theme")
    )
)

shinyApp(
    ui = dashboardPage(
        header,
        dashboardSidebar(),
        dashboardBody(
            shinyDashboardThemes(
                theme = input$theme
            ),
        )
    ),
    server = function(input, output) { }
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not put the `dropdownButton` in the `dashboardHeader`.

Instead you can put it in the `dashboardBody` or `dashboardSidebar` and have it updated like this :

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(dashboardthemes)

shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title = "Dashboard Demo"),
    dashboardSidebar(),
    dashboardBody(
      dropdownButton(
        radioButtons(inputId = 'theme',
                     label = 'Dashboard Theme',
                     choices =  c('blue_gradient', 'boe_website', 'grey_light','grey_dark',
                                  'onenote', 'poor_mans_flatly', 'purple_gradient'))
      ),
      uiOutput("myTheme")
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output) { 
    output$myTheme <- renderUI( shinyDashboardThemes(theme = input$theme))
    }
)
```

Comment: thanks.  Is there any way to put something else in the header  that I can choose from a list of themes? @HubertL

Comment: Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46231234/login-button-in-shinydashboard-dashboardheader)