# Add logo to shinydashboard title

Tags: html, r, shiny, shinydashboard

I want to add a logo to a shinydashboard title. I checked out this thread: [Adding a company Logo to ShinyDashboard header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31440564/adding-a-company-logo-to-shinydashboard-header)

Based on that, I 
[made the following code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5br3T.png)

This however, has a problem: It does not recognize the .png file (
[to see, click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V15A3.png))

list.files() however does say that the .png is in my directory.

Any pointers to what is going on or which direction I should be looking into?

Comment: Your image file has to be in the `www` subdirectory for it to work

Comment: Have you tried to put the png file in the www folder ?

Comment: And please do not post code as image.

Comment: @erocoar this worked! Thanks