# How to put a logo here? Shiny apps R

Tags: html, css, r, shinydashboard, shinyapps

[image]

Hi,

I need to put a logo in this red place, I already tried:

```
cabecalho <- dashboardHeader(title = "Test", titleWidth = '300px')
cabecalho$children[[2]]$children <-  tags$a(href='http://mycompanyishere.com',
                                                        tags$img(src='logo.png',height='50',width='100'))
```

But this gave me the image inside the "Test" title.

Comment: Have you tried these solutions? https://stackoverflow.com/q/31440564/680068 https://stackoverflow.com/q/21996887/680068

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem just adding this to dashboardHeader:

```
dashboardHeader(title = "Report", titleWidth = '240px', 
                             tags$li(a(href = 'http://www.site.com.br',
                                       img(src = 'logo.png',
                                           title = "Company Home", height = "30px"),
                                       style = "padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:10px; padding-right:17px;"),
                                       class = "dropdown")
                             
                             )
```