# R shiny: how to embed a background image in a plot created with rCharts / Highcharts?

Tags: javascript, r, highcharts, shiny, rcharts

I have an `R shiny` app containing a few `Highcharts` plots that were created with `rCharts` package. I would like to include a background image (sourced locally from my hard drive) in one of the plots.

I found an example on Highcharts website using `plotBackgroundImage` option, see [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/chart/plotbackgroundimage/).

I adapted it to `rCharts`, which works great. I was able to source the image via url or locally:

```
require(rCharts)    

# img_src <- '<path-to-the-folder>/skies.jpg' this works also
img_src <- 'https://www.highcharts.com/samples/graphics/skies.jpg'

p <- Highcharts$new()
p$chart(type='line', plotBackgroundImage=img_src)
p$xAxis(categories=LETTERS[1:10])
p$series(data=sample(10,10), color='#303030')
p
```

**However, in the `shiny` app, the image only comes up when sourced from url. I cannot get it to work when sourced locally:**

```
require(shiny)
require(rCharts)

ui <- fluidPage(
    mainPanel(showOutput("chart", "HighCharts"))
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$chart <- renderChart({

    # img_src <- '<path-to-the-folder>/skies.jpg' # this doesn't work
    img_src <- 'https://www.highcharts.com/samples/graphics/skies.jpg'

    p <- Highcharts$new()
    p$chart(type='line', plotBackgroundImage=img_src)
    p$xAxis(categories=LETTERS[1:10])
    p$series(data=sample(10,10), color='#303030')
    p$addParams(dom='chart')
    p
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Is there a way to locally source the background image in this case? Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

---

**UPDATE:**

I found that it works when the image is included in the `www` folder as suggested in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21998722/4658448). However, my image (heatmap) is changing based on the reactive input. It is more practical to render a temporary `png` file in `tempdir` and source it from there. **Is there a way to source the image straight from the temporary directory?**