# How to insert a background image in r highcharts?

Tags: r, highcharts, background-image, r-highcharter

I have created a `line plot` using `highchart` and I am looking to **insert a background image** to the plot. Referred to **SO** post [R shiny: how to embed a background image in a plot created with rCharts / Highcharts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35528694/r-shiny-how-to-embed-a-background-image-in-a-plot-created-with-rcharts-highch) and tried adding `plotBackgroundImage` to the plot but it doesn't work.

```
        mtcars %>% 
  hchart(type = "line", plotBackgroundImage = "folder/image_name.jpg",
                   name = "Covid test", 
                   hcaes(x = wt, 
                        y = mpg, col = cyl))
```

**UPDATE**

Plot result without image background:
[image]

**Update2**

Doesn't work for reading jpg from local directories:

```
highchart() %>% 
  hc_add_series(
    type = "line",
    data = mtcars, hcaes(x = wt, y = mpg)
  ) %>% 
   hc_chart(events = list(load = JS("function() {
      var chart = this; chart.update({
        chart: {
          type: 'line',
          plotBackgroundImage: 'E:/3. R/Covid19 clean data & app 2021-Apr-03/Covid 19 images/coronavirus-4972480_1920.jpg'
        }
      }); 
    }
    ")
  ))
```

[image]

works when read thro' url:

```
highchart() %>% 
  hc_add_series(
    type = "line",
    data = mtcars, hcaes(x = wt, y = mpg)
  ) %>% 
   hc_chart(events = list(load = JS("function() {
      var chart = this; chart.update({
        chart: {
          type: 'line',
          plotBackgroundImage: 'https://www.highcharts.com/samples/graphics/skies.jpg'
        }
      }); 
    }
    ")
  ))
```

[image]

**Update3:**
I gave all Permissions for this folder and still not getting background Image
[image]

Comment: You mean the path to this file is not working properly?

Comment: the path is working but I am not getting an image background in the plot. I have also added `readJPEG` and tried `hchart(type = "line", plotBackgroundImage = readJPEG("Covid 19 images/coronavirus-4972480_1920.jpg")` just to make sure if Image is getting read or not but in this case plot is just processing and nothing appears.

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach and let us know if it works now:

```
library('highcharter')
highchart() %>%
  hc_add_series(
    data = list(5, 4, 3, 5)
  ) %>%
  hc_chart(events = list(load = JS("function() {
      var chart = this; chart.update({
        chart: {
          type: 'line',
          plotBackgroundImage: 'https://www.highcharts.com/samples/graphics/skies.jpg'
        }
      }); 
    }
    ")
  ))
```

Useful links:

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.plotBackgroundImage
https://www.highcharts.com/blog/tutorials/working-with-highcharts-javascript-syntax-in-r/?fbclid=IwAR2BQSMAn67QbgwGjWK9MzjvmGEI3S5DABrUWq5ppPR7zxQ56ikXmwho8PQ

Comment: Its only `working` when I am using a `url` for image but doesn't work when I use image from `local directory`. I have updated my post, see `Update2`

Comment: This may be related to some access limitations, see a similar topic here: https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=36359

It seems that this is not just a problem in R.

Comment: Thanks @madepiet but I have tried again after giving all permissions for the image folder but still not getting the image. Not sure what other permissions it will require, see `Update3` section of the post. I think I will leave this here as it is not working !!