# local image in shiny app without img(src())?

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to include a local image file in my shiny app, following these instructions:

[Embedding Image in Shiny App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21996887/embedding-image-in-shiny-app)

However, my IT networks security, for some reason, prevents R from reading that image.

- I can confirm it is an IT security blockage, because the same exact code and file/directory structure works when I move to another computer.
- It is also strange, because I am able to read other files from that folder, because other commands like `read.csv()` are not blocked. I dont know what subroutines go on inside `img(src())` but my network does not like it.

Any alternative ways to embed an image in a shiny app ui?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Maybe with base64 encoding:

```
b64 <- base64enc::dataURI(file="myfile.png", mime="image/png")

ui <- fluidPage(
 img(src=b64)  
)

server <- function(input, output) {

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Where `myfile.png` is in the same folder as the app.

Comment: Nice @Stéphane Laurent! Thanks!