# Image failing to display in R shiny

Tags: r, image, shiny

I feel like there is really silly mistake, but I can't solve this myself and it is driving me crazy. To simply put, Rshiny is not display the image.

I put the source image in www directory in same path as the Rscript file, yet something is wrong.

The code I used are below:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    titlePanel(title=div(img(height = 100,
                             width = 100,
                             src = "dummy-logo.png"), "dummy")),
    sidebarLayout(...
```

This is the pathway for my image.

[image]

Here is the directory.:

[image]

Yet Rshiny could not find the image:

[image]

I looked around other posts but I am still not sure where I went wrong. I am pretty sure this is some really dumb mistake that I will be ashamed of but as of now, it is driving me nuts.  Thank you.

Comment: I don't see an .Rproj file in the directory, are you sure that this is the working directory your app is starting from?

Comment: Try the full path.  Then see if you can use `~/`.  The path for the assets in  Shiny (or knitr) is not necessarily what you think.

Comment: How do you run your shinyapp ? By executing your code as if it was a classical code (sourcing from the terminal for example) or using the Run App button in RStudio ?

Comment: I am running by Run App button in RStudio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked this answer? [Embedding Image in Shiny App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21996887/embedding-image-in-shiny-app)

Maybe rewrite the  titlePanel to:

```
titlePanel(title=div(id="dummy", img(height = 100,
                         width = 100,
                         src = "dummy-logo.png"))),
```

And check if the image is really named - **dummy-logo.png**.

Otherwise i would suggest you create a New Project in RStudio -> New Directory -> Shiny Web Application. Put your ui and server functions in there.
Create the www-folder, put your image in there and it should work like that.

Comment: This is what I did. I just deleted my entire folder and file and made new project/directory.  Although it is kind of brute way to solve it, your second suggestion indeed work.

Comment: I've had a similar strange problem.  Solved it be renaming my 'app.R' file to 'app' which my Mac automatically puts a '.R' on the end, then it worked fine.