# Resize Embedding Image in Shiny App

Tags: r, shiny

With reference to the answer presented here by Kay https://stackoverflow.com/a/21998722/9373320, I want to reduce the inserted image size to 50% both height and width.

`mainPanel(
   img(src='myImage.png', align = "right"),
  ### the rest of your code
  )`

Please help.

Answer (score 18):

Just type height and width in the image tag:

```
img(src="src", height="50%", width="50%", align="right")
```

Comment: In this answer you could just keep the parameter `width="100%"` and get the same result, without the "height" parameter. But I am not shure if this is what was asked, because in this solution you are transforming the image to 50% of screen width, but you are not necessarally reducing the image to 50% of it's original size.

Comment: Thanks SeGa, its woking. I also got that below code is also working `img(src='Image.png',style="width: 50px")`.