# Image output in shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I am trying to include an image in a shiny app. I want: "if it is type 1 plot "this image", if it is type 0 plot "this other image". I know that I have to put the jpg files into the folder where the app.R is and then call it but I do not know how.

This is the code I have used until now (it works), I just have to include the images in the render.

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Myapp"),

  #Inputs
  dateInput(inputId = "dob", label="Birth"),
  dateInput(inputId = "ad", label="Date"),
  actionButton("Submit", icon("fas fa-magic"), label="Submit"),


  #Outputs
  textOutput(outputId = "textR"),
  imageOutput(outputId = "imageR1"),
  imageOutput(outputId="imageR2")
)



# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {
  #my output should be named textR and imageR1, imageR2

  observeEvent(input$Submit, 
           output$textR<-renderText({
             v1<-as.numeric(as.Date(input$ad,format="%Y/%m/%d") - as.Date(input$dob, format="%Y/%m/%d"))/30.5
             value_v1<-ifelse(v1>48, "type1", "type2")
             print(value_v1)
           }))

}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is bad practice to define an output object inside an `observeEvent`. In this case, independent on the choice of how to switch the images, I would advice to use an `eventReactive` - let's call that `myval`. That creates a reactive which only changes when a certain event happens, in this case a click on the submit button. We can then refer to this in the body of the `renderText` statement, so that can simply become:

```
  output$textR<-renderText({
    print(myval())
  })
```

Secondly, for the outputting of images, you should place those in the `www` directory, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21996887/embedding-image-in-shiny-app). We can then create an ui element with `renderUI` and `UIOutput`, in which we use the value of our `eventReactive` `myval()` to select the image to display.

A working example is given below. Note that I saved it as app.R, and used the folder structure of the referred link, so:

```
| shinyApp/
    | app.R
    | www/
       | zorro.jpg
       | notzorro.jpg
```

Hope this helps!

[image]

---

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Myapp"),

  #Inputs
  dateInput(inputId = "dob", label="Birth"),
  dateInput(inputId = "ad", label="Date"),
  actionButton("Submit", icon("fas fa-magic"), label="Submit"),

  #Outputs
  textOutput(outputId = "textR"),
  uiOutput(outputId = "my_ui")
)



# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {

    myval <- eventReactive(input$Submit,
                         {
                           v1<-as.numeric(as.Date(input$ad,format="%Y/%m/%d") - as.Date(input$dob, format="%Y/%m/%d"))/30.5
                           return(ifelse(v1>48, "type1", "type2"))
                         })

  output$textR<-renderText({
    print(myval())
  })

  output$my_ui<-renderUI({
    if(myval()=='type1')
      img(src='zorro.jpg', height = '300px')
    else
      img(src='notzorro.jpg', height = '300px')
  })

}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: A comprehensive answer with working code and a animated gif of the output, all within 20 minutes of the question being asked. Fantastic!