# Shiny App with Embedded Photo not Working

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to work through the `R Studio Shiny` tutorials.  The second tutorial includes embedding an image into an `app`.  It seems straight-forward and a similar question-and-answer here seems to use the same approach:

[Embedding Image in Shiny App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21996887/embedding-image-in-shiny-app)

However, I cannot get this approach to work.  Here is a stripped-down version of `R Studio`'s second tutorial code and a screenshot of the result I get.  I have the `png` file in my working directory.  Must the photo be placed somewhere else?

```
setwd('C:/Users/mark_/Documents/RShiny/')

library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel('Shiny App with Photo'),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      h2("Installation"),
      p("Shiny is on CRAN"),
      br(),
      img(src = "myScreenshot.png", height = 70, width = 200),
      br()
    ),
    mainPanel(
      h1("Shiny"),
      p("Shiny is a package from RStudio"), 
      br()
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

**EDIT to Add Additional Steps Taken**

When I originally posted my issue with `R Shiny` I was using the default `R GUI`.  I have since switched to `R Studio` in case `R Shiny` works best that way.  But this has not helped.

I have installed `Rtools` and added the following code to the very top of the above `app.R` file:

```
install.packages('zip')
install.packages('shinyjs')
install.packages('shinydashboard')
install.packages('shinyBS')
install.packages('shinyWidgets')

library(zip)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyBS)
library(shinyWidgets)

install.packages('backports')
library(backports)
install.packages('devtools')
library(devtools)

rm(list=ls())
getwd()
setwd('C:/Users/mark_/Documents/RShiny/')
getwd()
library(shiny)
```

But this has not helped either.

As suggested by @MattB below I have created a subfolder named `www` inside the folder `C:/Users/mark_/Documents/RShiny` and place the file `myScreenshot.png` inside that `www` subfolder.  However, this has not solved the problem.  The image still does not appear.

I also tried placing the file `myScreenshot.png` inside that `www` subfolder of the `RStudio` folder under `Program Files` (`C:\Program Files\RStudio\www`) but this has not helped.

The image does not appear under the `Open in Browser` tab or under the `http://` tab.

There are two options I have not yet tried.  Perhaps I must change the name of the folder containing the `app.R` file (`C:/Users/mark_/Documents/RShiny`) to something other than `RShiny`.  Perhaps that is confusing `R Studio`.

There is another issue that perhaps is preventing `R Studio` from locating the image file.  When I install an `R` package I get the following message:

```
> install.packages('reshape2')
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/mark_/Documents/R/win-library/4.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
also installing the dependency ‘plyr’
```

I end up with both:

```
C:\Program Files\R\R-4.0.0
C:\Users\mark_\Documents\R\win-library\4.0
```

I wonder whether that has anything to do with `R Studio` not being able to locate the image file.

Answer (score 0):

For any files to be available to the app user, they need to be placed in the `/www` directory within your app folder. You don't need to change your code otherwise, as the user's browser will see this folder automatically.

Comment: If I create a subfolder named `www` inside the folder `RShiny` and place the file `myScreenshot.png` inside that `www` subfolder the image still does not appear.  Although, I now see what you are suggesting mentioned in the tutorial.

Comment: I don't know then I'm afraid - that should work. You can try to get to the image directly in your browser when the app is running - if you can, then it's a problem with the shiny code, if you can't then it's not picking up the picture for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the `R` script to run in `R Studio` and display an image file by following suggestions by Dean Attali @DeanAttali at this website.

https://deanattali.com/blog/building-shiny-apps-tutorial/

I renamed the folder to `Shineexample2` and placed that folder directly in the Documents folder.  (`C:\Users\mark_\Documents\Shineexample2`) This was not one of Dean Attali's suggestions but the rest of the following was or was at least how I interpreted his suggestions.

This new folder `Shineexample2` only contained the file `app.R` and the `www` subfolder containing the image file.

I opened the `app.R` file in `R Studio`, not the default `R GUI`, using `File` then `Open File...`.

Then I clicked on `Run App` in the upper middle area of the `R Studio GUI`.

The file ran as expected.

The above process differed from my earlier attempts in several ways.  Previously the `app.R` file was in a `folder` with a different name and containing many other `files` and `subfolders`.  Usually I opened the file `app.R` in `Notepad` and copied and pasted its contents into `R Studio`.  Then I selected all of the code and ran it using `Code` then `Run Selected Line(s)`.  I never noticed the `Run App` term at the top of the `R Studio Gui` before visiting Dean's website.

If I determine exactly which of these changes was most critical to successful execution of my code I may edit this answer in the future to provide that information.

Here are the complete contents of the `app.R` file that ran successfully.

```
#
# Stack_Overflow_Shiny_question_about_embedding_images_May22_2020.R
#
# install.packages('shiny')
# install.packages('zip')
# install.packages('shinyjs')
# install.packages('shinydashboard')
# install.packages('shinyBS')
# install.packages('shinyWidgets')
# install.packages('devtools')
# 

library(shiny)
library(zip)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyBS)
library(shinyWidgets)

install.packages('backports')
library(backports)

library(devtools)


rm(list=ls())
getwd()
setwd('C:/Users/mark_/Documents/Shineexample2/')
getwd()
library(shiny)


ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel('Shiny App with Photo'),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      h2("Installation"),
      p("Shiny is on CRAN"),
      br(),
      img(src = "RStudio.png", height = 70, width = 200),
      br()
    ),
    mainPanel(
      h1("Shiny"),
      p("Shiny is a package from RStudio"), 
      br()
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```