# Shiny Dashboard - How to place an image from www folder into a dashboard box

Tags: shinydashboard

I am looking for a simple method to retrieve a .png from a file folder, and place it in a shiny dashboard. I tried the suggested img(src='myImage.png', align = "right") from [Embedding Image in Shiny App](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21996887/ddg#21998722) but I continue to get an error "unused arguments (src = "Slide1.PNG", align = "right")". I've tried to place my image in a dashboard, box, etc. without success.

Answer (score 0):

You should show your code so that someone can review and point out issues in your usage.  It really depends on where you want to place your image. The solution you pointed to shows you how to place an image in the main panel.  The code below shows how to place an image in the header Title or to the right of title.

```
dashboardHeader(title = div("Testing", 
                            img(src = 'YBS.png',
                                title = "A Clinical Graphics Application", height = "30px"),
                            style = "position: relative; margin:-3px 0px 0px 5px; display:right-align;"
), 
titleWidth=450,
tags$li(div(
          img(src = 'YBS.png',
              title = "A Clinical Graphics Application", height = "30px"),
          style = "padding-top:10px; padding-right:100px;"),
        class = "dropdown"),...
```

In a tabBox the following should work

```
div(tags$img(height="50px", src="YBS.png", style="text-align: right;"))
```