# Why are my jpg and png's not processing on R Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, data-science, rshiny

Quick question: I am working with R Shiny, and I am trying to embed pictures onto my app. Problem: when I load them, I can't seem to get the jpg or png on the screen. (I tried both file types.) Only a misloaded file icon appears. How do you get this fixed? Any help would be much appreciated.

I tried a variety of options, but here is the simplest code. I'm just trying to remove as many variables as possible. The skiing.png should be in my folder.

```
mainPanel(tags$img(src="skiing.png"),width=2)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21998722/3087927

Comment: Yes, I saw that  page, but nothing worked on my screen. I have no idea how to use CSS, so I'd try to avoid it. Outside of CSS, any ideas?

Comment: CSS? just put it in a www folder like the answer I linked to says....

Answer (score 0):

Create a `www` sub-directory in your project directory and move the pictures there. There is no need to change the `src` path.

```
| project_dir/
  | app.R
  | www/
    |skiing.png
```

Please try this minimal example, with the image in the `www` directory. If this does not work, either your Shiny server is configured differently from the default or something else is wrong.

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(), 
      mainPanel(tags$img(src="skiing.png"),width=2) 
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) { }
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Hmmmm. I moved the picture in the www folder, but the image still won't render. It's a png screenshot. Any reason why this wouldn't work?