# Having Trouble with Image Output in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to connect a logo image to the footer of my shiny Dashboard but am having trouble with the image displaying itself. I'll put the code snippet that I used for it below.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
    tags$footer(img(src="Logo.jpg", height = 25, width = 50), align = "right")
)
```

I know that the app is picking up on the command because when I run it, it shows a blank image template as such:
[Image of Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQCsi.png)

I'm relatively new to shiny, so is it like HTML where I have to make sure the image is in the code folder? I don't have anything inside my server logic yet so maybe I need to connect the image to that?

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21996887/embedding-image-in-shiny-app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a new directory named www in your code directory and put your image there, and then reference the new image path.